# Do we believe that the distribution of spacings of successive critical zeros of zeta is log-symmetric?

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta-function

Let $\gamma^{+}(T)$ be the imaginary part of the critical zero of $\zeta$ closest to $1/2+iT$ with $\gamma^{+}(T)\ge T$ and define similarly $\gamma^{-}(T)$ with a reversed inequality. Let $g(T)$ be the normalized gap around $T$, I.e. the ratio $\frac{\gamma^{+}(T)-\gamma^{-}(T)}{g_{av}(T)}$ where the denominator is the average spacing of two consecutive critical zeros around height $T$.

Let $\delta_{r,\lambda}(T)$ the proportion of $0<t<T$ such that $g(t)\in (\lambda-r,\lambda+r)$.

Is there a continuous strictly increasing function $f$ with $f(0)=0$ and tending to infinity as the variable does so such that $\delta_{r,\lambda}(T)\sim\delta_{f(r),1/\lambda}(T)$?

Edit : if $f$ ever turns out to be the identity, would it be interesting to consider $r$ as a function of $T$ like for example $r(T)=1/T$?